# How to Change All Links with javascript

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, hyperlink

I want to change all links of my site. Suppose a link given by .Example http://www.google.com/ changes to http://www.mysite.com/?redirect=http://www.google.com/

i have my own redirector just i need to change the links via javascript for all url

Comment: What have you tried so far? Note that you can edit your question to update it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].href = "http://www.mysite.com/?redirect=" + anchors[i].href
}
```

You can then make the code run on page-load by wrapping it in a function linked to window.onload event:

```
window.onload = function() {
       /* onload code */
}
```

Comment: 100% Working! Thanks! Stackoverflow is great!

Comment: But if i put it in blogger template head then it dont works becuase it shows error "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup."

Comment: But now i will use it on external javascript file!

Comment: http://ishanplus.blogspot.com/2012/11/increase-your-google-page-rank-search.html

I used it on this url! Thanks.... give me link of your website... i need to give credits to you

Comment: I think this answer is not completely correct because href could contain mailto:someemail@test.com and this hrefs should not be changed. I think solution should check if href is correct URL address. If not then we should not change this link

Answer (score 3):

If you use javascript without a framework, you can use the following lines:

```
var links, i, le;
links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i = 0, le = links.length; i < le; i++) {
    links[i].href = "http://www.mysite.com/?redirect=" + encodeURIComponent(links[i].href);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another version with some checks for local links and [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
var links = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));
links.forEach(function(link) {
    var href = link.href;

    if (href.length && href.substring(0, 1) !== "#" && href.substring(0, 1) !== "/") {
        link.href = "http://www.mysite.com/?redirect=" + encodeURIComponent(link.href);
        console.log(link.href);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function(i, e)
{
    var current = $(this);

    current.attr('href', 'http://www.mysite.com/?redirect=' + encodeURIComponent(current.attr('href')))
});
```